How to Backup and Compress /etc Directory in Yocto Rootfs Before Packaging?
I need some help with a Yocto project. I want to back up the /etc directory from the compiled rootfs, compress it into a .tgz file, and store it back in the recovery folder within the rootfs.
Currently, I have written an etc-image.bb file

DESCRIPTION = "Create a tarball of the /etc directory"

LICENSE = "CLOSED"

tarball_name="${IMAGE_NAME}-etc"

BACKUP_PATH ?= "/recovery"


FILES_${PN} += "${BACKUP_PATH}"

do_fetch[noexec] = "1"
do_configure[noexec] = "1"

do_install () {
    echo "Running do_image_etc..."

    core_image_rootfs="${TMPDIR}/work/${MACHINE_ARCH}-poky-linux/core-image-minimal/1.0-r0/rootfs"
    etc_dir="${core_image_rootfs}/etc"


    if [ ! -d "${etc_dir}" ]; then
        echo "ERROR: /etc directory does not exist in rootfs."
        exit 1
    fi


    mkdir -p ${WORKDIR}/${tarball_name}

    echo "Copying /etc content..."
    cp -a ${etc_dir}/* ${WORKDIR}/${tarball_name}/ || {
        echo "ERROR: Failed to copy /etc content."
        exit 1
    }

    echo "Creating etc tarball..."
    tar -zcvf ${WORKDIR}/${tarball_name}.tgz -C ${WORKDIR}/${tarball_name} . || {
        echo "ERROR: Failed to create tar file."
        exit 1
    }

    echo "Tarball created successfully."

    ln -sf ${tarball_name}.tgz ${WORKDIR}/etc_backup.tgz || {
        echo "ERROR: Failed to create symbolic link."
        exit 1
    }
    echo "Symbolic link created: etc_backup.tgz -> ${tarball_name}.tgz"


    install -d ${D}${BACKUP_PATH}
    install -m 644 ${WORKDIR}/${tarball_name}.tgz ${D}${BACKUP_PATH} || {
        echo "ERROR: Failed to install tarball."
        exit 1
    }
    install -m 644 ${WORKDIR}/etc_backup.tgz ${D}${BACKUP_PATH} || {
        echo "ERROR: Failed to install symbolic link."
        exit 1
    }

    echo "Installation completed successfully."
}



and declared it in the core-image-minimal.bb file as follows:
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " 
etc-image 
"
However, when I run bitbake core-image-minimal, it fails because the
ERROR: /var directory does not exist in rootfs.
I suspect that I need to ensure etc-image runs after the rootfs is built but before the image is packaged. How can I modify my setup to achieve this?
Thanks in advance for your help!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56712338/how-do-i-modify-a-rootfs-configuration-file-with-yocto It's work
